# Cannot read property of 'appendchild' of null in a For-Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, appendchild

I have a small database that I have retrieved the data from and stored in a HTML table.

This table contains 3 columns and 3 rows.

What I want to do is via javascript create a div for each row, then within this create a div for each cell in that row of the table (to allow me to style it in CSS).

I have created a number of For loops to go through and attempt this, my problem is the second for loop I have created, it goes through once and I receive an error of "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null". I am not sure why it is doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var getTable = document.getElementById('projectsTable');

var rowLength = getTable.rows.length;

for (i =0; i< rowLength; i++) {
    var divName = 'projects' + i;
    block = document.createElement('div');
    block.id = divName;
    document.getElementById('javascript').appendChild(block);


    var getCells = getTable.rows.item(i).cells;

    var cellLength = getCells.length;

    for (var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
        var divName2 = 'projects' + j;
        var projectInfo = 'info' + j;
        info = document.createElement('div');
        info.id = projectInfo;
        document.getElementById(divName2).appendChild(info);


        var cellVal = getCells.item(j).innerHTML;
        var getDiv = document.getElementById(projectInfo);
        getDiv.innerHTML = cellVal;

    }

}
```

The first for loop creates the div for the whole row and attaches it to a div in the page that already exists, then I get the error on the 2nd for loop.

Comment: Wouldnt block.appendChild(info); be more simple? Since block is your document.getElementById(divName2). Anyway, it does not work because var divName2 = 'projects' + j; should be var divName2 = 'projects' + i;

Comment: Depending on the line number, either document.getElementById('javascript') or document.getElementById(divName2) is returning null.  You should be able to tell which via a debugger.

Comment: Changing it to I won't work. That will mean that each row will be put into the same div instead of creating new ones.

Comment: I just need to figure out why it's returning null#

Comment: Like I said, you are lookg for project + j instead of project + i in your subloop. It works for the first turn since both are 0, yet not on further ones. Your divName2 should equal divName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using many unnecessary variables and definitions. For example divName2 should be same as divName and thus redundant.
I hope this example helps you out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadTable(){
                var tT = document.getElementById('projectsTable'); //Source table
                var tJ = document.getElementById('javascript'); //New clone container
                if (tT && tJ){
                    for(var i=0, j=tT.rows.length;i<j;i++){
                        var tP = document.createElement('div'); //Our project div(:=tr)
                        tP.id = 'projects' + i.toString();

                        for(k=0, l=tT.rows.item(i).cells.length;k<l;k++){
                            var tI = document.createElement('div'); //Our info div(:=td)
                            tI.id = 'info' + k.toString();
                            tI.innerHTML = (i+1)*k;
                            tP.appendChild(tI); //We still have the correct project from above, so we just use it.
                        };

                        tJ.appendChild(tP); //Adding project to the dom
                    };
                };
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'loadTable();'>
        <table id = 'projectsTable'>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
        </table>

        <div id = 'javascript'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes the loop perfectly! However I am at a bit of a loss how to actually get the values from each cell. I can't see how the InnerHTML setting is now linked to the actual table

Comment: Change the example tI.innerHTML with this
tI.innerHTML = tT.rows.item(i).cells[k].innerHTML;

Comment: Do you still need any further help on this?

Comment: Apologies I have been away since this. But no it works perfectly. Your help was much appreciated!!